# How to Extract JSON value outside of Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

At the moment I can loop through my JSON array ''**pos**" and store all the variables within that into a array list.

**What I'm trying to do:**

How can I easily parse **tour & date** which are outside the "**pos**" array?

I would like to store the values in  "**tour**" & "**date**" into two separate string variables.

**My understanding:** json.getJSONArray() can't be used in this case, as json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES); only pulls in "pos" array data.

**JSON Structure:**

```
{
    "pos": [
        {
            "pos": "",
            "person": "",
            "thur": "",
            "score": "",
            "round": ""
       },
        {
            "pos": "2",
            "person": "John",
            "thur": "",
            "score": "16",
            "round": "3"
       },
       {
            "pos": "3",
            "person": "Peter Lynch",
            "thur": "",
            "score": "5",
            "round": "2"
       }
    ],
    "tour": "Camping",
    "date": "Thursday Jul 23 - Sunday Jul 26, 2015"
  }
```

**Code to Parse JSON pos array:**

```
 // ALL JSON nodes
private static final String TAG_MESSAGES = "pos";
private static final String TAG_ID = "pos";
private static final String TAG_FROM = "person";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "thur";
private static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "round";
private static final String TAG_DATE = "score";


// These are outside of array pos    
private static final String TAG_TOUR = "tour";
private static final String TAG_TOURDATE = "date";



 try {
            inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);

            inbox.toString();


            // looping through All messages
            for (int i = 0; i < inbox.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = inbox.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,    String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_FROM, from);
                map.put(TAG_EMAIL, mailer);
                map.put(TAG_DATE, date);
                map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                inboxList.add(map);
```

Comment: you can write json.getString("tour");

Comment: Well I'm using  inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES); in my code, that only takes in the pos array, the tour & date falls outside that array. Sorry I'm new to this

Comment: yes below inbox=json.getJSONArray() write this String tour=json.getString("tour")

Answer (score 2):

as you can get a `JSONArray` from your json , you can get `String` from it too.

something like this :

```
json.getString("tour");
json.getString("date");
```

Comment: But in my code I'm looping through json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);  - that's the "pos" array, so tour & date fall outside that. If that makes sense, so getString("tour") wouldn't work in that case

Comment: @SarahBoland, honestly it doesn't make case. that code will work either outside ur loop or inside. but common sense suggests that you have it outside the loop where u inited the JSONArray

Comment: Sorry i'm new to this, and I had tired this approach and I always get NULL back.

Comment: @SarahBoland make sure you that your outter json doesn't contain those two keys

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
String tour = "", date = "";

try {
if(json.has("tour"))
            tour= json.getString("tour");
if(json.has("date"))
            date= json.getString("date");

} Catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Which will not crash even if there is no date/ tour key(if missing)

Comment: Also get NULL for both String's here

Comment: @SarahBoland use `optString` instead of  `getString`

Answer (score 1):

```
        inbox = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MESSAGES);
        String tour=json.getString("tour");
        String date=json.getString("date");
```

Comment: I get NULL for both tour & date when I use this